# Conditional Cell Substitution in Pandas, Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a very long spreadsheet (CSV) wherein overly long URLs have been moved from the "Website" column to the Notes column a few columns over.  Unfortunately, the convention for marking such cells has not been consistent (some say "see over," others might say "See over-long url," but I believe all include "see over" in varying cases).  I'm using a pretty complex pandas script to create a corrupted pivot table, but I'm still flailing on figuring out all of panda's shortcuts.  How would I create a condition to move the notes column cell for a given row into the website column cell on the condition that the latter contains "see over"?  In this case, I also want to blank out the notes column cell (in other cases, I want to keep that cell intact).

On a similar note, how would I create a condition so that if the value in column "Foo" says "Bar," I can ignore writing that to the output and instead put a value in column "Foo?" that says "Yes"?

Comment: Have a look at the [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.DataFrame.replace) method to standardize the naming. You'll get more specific examples if you provide a short sample problem and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I don't think I'd try anything too cute: simply figure out which rows need to have things moved and then move them.  Starting from a frame like

```
>>> df
                      Website                               Notes Other
0    http://stackoverflow.com                 home away from home     a
1  http://mapleleafs.nhl.com/                                1967     b
2                    see over  http://www.example.com/not_so_long     c
3       http://www.colts.com/            the Luck of the Hoosiers     d
```

I'd do something like

```
>>> to_shift_over = df.Website.str.lower().str.contains("see over")
>>> df.loc[to_shift_over, "Website"] = df["Notes"]
>>> df.loc[to_shift_over, "Notes"] = ""
```

producing

```
>>> df
                              Website                     Notes Other
0            http://stackoverflow.com       home away from home     a
1          http://mapleleafs.nhl.com/                      1967     b
2  http://www.example.com/not_so_long                               c
3               http://www.colts.com/  the Luck of the Hoosiers     d
```

---

Using `str` on a `Series` is a handy way to perform vector ops on them:

```
>>> df["Website"].str
<pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0xa9dcfac>
>>> df["Website"].str.lower()
0      http://stackoverflow.com
1    http://mapleleafs.nhl.com/
2                      see over
3         http://www.colts.com/
Name: Website, dtype: object
>>> df["Website"].str.lower().str.contains("see over")
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Website, dtype: bool
```

And then we can use that boolean array to index into `df` using `.loc`:

```
>>> df.loc[to_shift_over]
    Website                               Notes Other
2  see over  http://www.example.com/not_so_long     c
>>> df.loc[to_shift_over, "Website"]
2    see over
Name: Website, dtype: object
```

Comment: So I tried adding `if df4['Notes'].str.lower().str.contains('www'):` to ensure that a website is listed in Notes (there are several notes columns and the individuals creating the original sheet used ad hoc standards), and I got back `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Yep, that's what would happen.  `df4['Notes'].str.lower().str.contains('www')` is a boolean array.  It might have all Trues, all Falses, or a mix.  The `if` tries to call `bool` on that series, basically, but there's no canonical way to decide whether an array of multiple bools should be considered True or not.  If you want to do something if every Note contains `www`, then you want `if df4(etc).all():`; if you want to do something if any of them, then `.any()`.  That's what the error message is saying, just maybe a little too concisely.

Comment: And if I add `.any` to the end of the row, I get `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`

Comment: This error comes back even if I try to solve it with `if df4['Notes'].fillna('missing').str.lower().str.contains('www').any():`

Comment: Edit: It seems to now actually be occurring on the next line, but you didn't get it - on line `df4.loc[to_move, 'Website'] = df4['Notes']`.  Both Website and Notes *can* be missing values.

Comment: I can't even get your code, as it is, to work; I still get `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` - I assume because ['Website'] and ['Notes'] contain null entries, but I can't even seem to prevent this with any conditions I've tried :/

Comment: Figured it out.  I was using fillna('') properly, but I had to move the to_shift_over *below* the fillna lines, which seems obvious now, but it was one of those simple script-order things that took all day to see...